# How can you drop an element from a xaml C#?

Tags: c#, mvvm

I am using MVVM architecture, when creating a view I want to remove an element if the user is not an admin. Here is the pseudo code that I currently have.

if is admin is false

remove admin panel from window

Comment: [FAQ on how to question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [Make it Minimal, Complete and Verfiable Example(MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: No need to remove it, simply bind the `IsVisible` property of the element in question.

Answer (score 0):

Frauke Nonnenmacher I went with your suggestion to bind the IsVisible property to the element.